# A complex optimization problem (maximize determinant of matrix)

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

**Background**

Assume we have a 2 columned matrix ${\bf P}$ and this matrix can be written as $${\bf P}= [ {\bf p_1 \,\,\,\, p_2}]$$  where ${\bf p_1}$ is the first column (vector) of ${\bf P}$ and ${\bf p_2}$ is the last column (vector) and assume we have another matrix ${\bf A}$.

I have seen a paper that expanded the following matrix multiplication ${\bf AP P^H A^H}$ (${\bf H}$ is hermitian: conjugate transpose) in the following way

$${\bf AP P^H A^H} = {\bf A}[ {\bf  p_1 \,\,\,\, p_2}][ {\bf  p_1 \,\,\,\, p_2}]^H {\bf A^H}={\bf Ap_1p_1^HA^H+ A{\bf p_2}{\bf p_2^H}A^H} $$

**My problem**

I am interested in a different matrix multiplication. Assume we have an additional matrix ${\bf W}$. I would like to expand matrix multiplication that is of the following form

$${\bf M}= {\bf W^HAP P^H A^HW}$$

so I thought of doing the same trick that is I defined $${\bf W}= [ {\bf w_1\,\,\,\, w_2}]$$

$${\bf M}={\bf W^HAP P^H A^HW}=[ {\bf  w_1 \,\,\,\, w_2]^H} ({\bf Ap_1p_1^HA^H+ A{\bf p_2}{\bf p_2^H}A^H})[ {\bf  w_1 \,\,\,\, w_2]} $$

$$=\begin{bmatrix}
    {\bf w_1^H}({\bf Ap_1p_1^HA^H+ A{\bf p_2}{\bf p_2^H}A^H}){\bf  w_1} & {\bf w_1^H}({\bf Ap_1p_1^HA^H+ A{\bf p_2}{\bf p_2^H}A^H}){\bf  w_2} \\
   {\bf w_2^H}({\bf Ap_1p_1^HA^H+ A{\bf p_2}{\bf p_2^H}A^H}){\bf  w_1} & {\bf w_2^H}({\bf Ap_1p_1^HA^H+ A{\bf p_2}{\bf p_2^H}A^H}){\bf  w_2}
  \end{bmatrix}$$

My first question, is my derivation correct?

Assuming my derivation is correct, my second question I would like to solve for the following optimization matrix

$$\max_{{\bf w_1,w_2,p_1,p_2}}   \log (|{\bf I}+ {\bf M}| )$$

it seems to me this is impossible to solve for, if yes can anyone help me with some ideas on how to simplify this complex problem, or give me hints ?

I assume the solution has to do with SVD decompostiion of $A$but I am not sure.
Thanks